# Group by display row with highet value column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table `opname` like this:

[image]

I want to select table opname with group by based id_barang and I want to display the row with the highest id of group by result.

I wrote query like this

```
SELECT 
    MAX(id), id_barang, tgl, ket, kondisi 
FROM  
    `opname` 
GROUP BY 
    id_barang
```

[image]

but why value of columns tgl, ket, kondisi it's not match with `max(id)` - how to fix that? I want to display row with the highest id of group by result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following using a sub-query:

```
SELECT id, id_barang, tgl, ket, kondisi FROM `opname` WHERE id IN (
    SELECT MAX(id) FROM `opname` GROUP BY id_barang
)
```

With the inner `SELECT` you get all the maximum IDs of the grouped result. The outer `SELECT` selects all rows from your original table with all these IDs.

Answer (score 1):

Your current query is not far off, except that it attempts to select non aggregate columns while using `GROUP BY`.  This doesn't make logical sense, because it isn't clear *which* values should be chosen for each `id_barang` group.  But if we join the `opname` table to your current query as a subquery, then we can identify the records you want to retain.

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM opname t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT id_barang, MAX(id) AS max_id
    FROM opname
    GROUP BY id_barang
) t2
    ON t1.id_barang = t2.id_barang AND    -- retain only MAX(id) records
       t1.id = t2.max_id                  -- for each barang_id
```